# How to sketch the phase portrait near the critical point at the origin.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A linear system and its general solution.

$dx/dt$ = $6x - 2y$

$dy/dt$ = $4x + 2y$

It has a general solution of this:

$$\begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t) \end{bmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix} cos(2t) \\ cos(2t)+sin(2t) \end{bmatrix} e^{4t} + B\begin{bmatrix} sin(2t) \\ sin(2t) - cos(2t) \end{bmatrix}e^{4t}$$

Sketch the phase portrait near the critical point at the origin.
Discuss the type and stability of the critical point.

I don't know how to approach this since I'm used to drawing in the 2 eigenvectors and figuring out if they face in or out against the origin. Then I would draw the orbits. How do I do this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a phase portrait for this system.

[image]

- What do you notice about the direction fields?
- What are your eigenvalues telling you about stability?
- What is happening to the solution curves as $t$ is increasing?

**Update**

Lets find the critical point, that is, where $x'$ and $y'$ are simultaneouly equal to zero.

We have:

- $6x - 2y = 0$
- $4x + 2y = 0$

This leads to a single critical point at $(0,0)$.

Next, the eigenvalues for this system are:

$$\lambda_{1,2} = 4 \pm 2i$$

Since we have complex conjugate, with positive real part, these are unstable spirals and that is what the phase portrait is telling us. Here is a handy [*stabilty reference*](http://www.math.psu.edu/tian/S2012Math251/Phase_portrait_reference_card.pdf) classifying eigenvalues.

So, we need to learn to do three things, find eigenvalues, find critical points and draw phase portraits.

Next, look at your $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ result. What do you notice as $t$ increases? Now, what if you plot $x(t)$ versus $y(t)$? You get the phase portrait showing that as $t$ increases, you get directions leaving the critical point off to infinity and this is unstable.

Comment: Outwards and all going in a clockwise direction? How is that found from the equation?

Comment: No worries! Thanks man!

Comment: Yeah, I've been sort of able to wrap my head around a couple of these problems. Having the trig really threw me off again. What's the best thing, knowing the stability reference and drawing with the idea in mind. Or trying to draw it without knowing the stability reference?

Comment: For linear system, we can classify stability from the eigenvalues (positive, negative, zero, imaginary ...), so that is sufficient. Once you know those, they tell you exactly what the phase portrait is going to basically look like. So, having a notion of that is helpful, but know how to draw phase portraits is a very useful analytical tool. They are even very handy when you get to nonlinear systems. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti: +1 nice pattern illustrating what is going on near that point.

Comment: Nice write-up, Amzoti. +1

Comment: And that's likewise :-)

Comment: @amzoti, Thanks man! big help! I just asked another question, it's on my profile. Perhaps you could help me out if you're not busy?

Comment: What software do you use to sketch a phase portrait?